# In PHP, is there a simple way to tell if a URL is a single file resource?

Tags: php, url

I'm writing code in PHP to find out the total size of a given webpage.  But if the URL points to a single file resource (like a png, gif, txt, etc. file) , then I won't need to parse the page that the URL passed in points to in order to see if there are any links to other resources (like .js, .css, etc files).

Comment: How about checking the MIME type: there should only be a small handful of document types that *do* require further parsing and processing.

Comment: You want to determine whether an URL leads to a non-HTML resource? Be more specific, by decomposing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parhaps parse the response and check MIME type. For example, if you are using cURL:

```
    <?php
    // Create a curl handle
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');

    // Execute
    curl_exec($ch);

    // Check if any error occured
    if(!curl_errno($ch))
    {
     $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

     echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'] .'<br>';
     echo 'Content type:' . $info['content_type'];
     // Parse based on content type.
    }

    // Close handle
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```